# turtlebot 2 kobuki base move forward

Tags: c++, ros

I want to move the turtlebot.package name is "forward" Firstly i created package inside my catkin_ws

```
$ catkin_create_pkg forward std_msgs rospy roscpp actionlib tf geometry_msgs move_base_msgs
```

Then i edit CMakeList

```
add_executable(gg src/g.cpp) and target_link_libraries(gg, ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Thirdly, i run these commands:

```
catkin_make
roscore
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:'pwd'

source ./devel/setup.bash
rosrun forward gg.cpp
```

gg.cpp:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <geometry_msgs/PointStamped.h>
#include <std_msgs/Header.h>
#include <iostream>


int main(){

 geometry_msgs::PointStamped p;
 geometry_msgs::PointStamped p1;
 p.header.stamp = ros::Time();
 std::string frame1 = "/camera_depth_optical_frame";
 p.header.frame_id = frame1.c_str();

 p.point.x = 0;
 p.point.y = 0;
 p.point.z = 1; // 1 meter

// std::string frame = "map";

 /*try
 {
   listener.transformPoint(frame,p,p1);
 }catch(tf::TransformException& ex) { ROS_ERROR("exception while transforming..."); }
*/
 // create message for move_base_simple/goal 
 geometry_msgs::PoseStamped msg;
 msg.header.stamp = ros::Time();
 std::string frame = "/map";
 msg.header.frame_id = frame.c_str();
 msg.pose.position = p1.point;
 msg.pose.orientation = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(0.0);
 //publisher.publish(msg);

}
```

errors:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named gg.cpp below /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/src/forward
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/src/forward/src/gg.cpp
```

what do you think about these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You name your executable `gg`:

```
add_executable(gg src/g.cpp) and target_link_libraries(gg, ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

But try to run the target `gg.cpp`

```
rosrun forward gg.cpp
```

try

```
rosrun forward gg
```

Comment: thanks problem solved.but now when running code, output is "waiting for the move_base action server".what do you think?

Comment: I have another question following the SendingSimpleGoals tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals , after running the executable, Waiting for the move_base action server to come up waits forever. Can anyone suggest me?